The positional relationship between parabolic hypersurface of revolution and hyperplane
Can we use the quadratic positive definite condition or the quadratic negative definite condition to determine that the quadratic hypersurface has no intersection with the plane?
Given mutually distinct $n$-dimensional non-zero constant vectors $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$, $\boldsymbol{\beta}$, $\boldsymbol{\gamma}\in\mathbb{R}^n$, and $\langle\boldsymbol{\gamma}-\boldsymbol{\beta},\boldsymbol{\beta}\rangle\ne0$. The hyperplane equation is $\langle\boldsymbol{\gamma}-\boldsymbol{\beta},\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{\beta}\rangle=0$ and the parabolic hypersurface of revolution equation are $\left\Vert\boldsymbol{\alpha}-\boldsymbol{\beta}\right\Vert^{2}\big\Vert\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{\alpha}\big\Vert^{2}=\langle\boldsymbol{\alpha}-\boldsymbol{\beta},\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{\beta}\rangle^2$, what are the conditions for intersection?
Is the following approach possible?
Homogeneize them all, introduce a parameter $t$ corresponding to the constant term, solve the constant term parameters in the hyperplane equation, then substitute this parameter into the quadratic hypersurface equation. Find the augmented Hessian matrix of the transformed quadratic form, which is the coefficient matrix of the quadratic form. Finally, the quadratic positive definite theory is used to construct the hypersurface intersection condition.
\begin{align*}
\langle\boldsymbol{\gamma}-\boldsymbol{\beta},\boldsymbol{x}-t\boldsymbol{\beta}\rangle&=0\\
\dfrac{\langle\boldsymbol{\gamma}-\boldsymbol{\beta},\boldsymbol{x}\rangle}{\langle\boldsymbol{\gamma}-\boldsymbol{\beta},\boldsymbol{\beta}\rangle}s&=t\\
\\
\Phi\colon\!=\left\Vert\boldsymbol{\alpha}-\boldsymbol{\beta}\right\Vert^{2}\big\Vert\boldsymbol{x}-t\boldsymbol{\alpha}\big\Vert^{2}&-\langle\boldsymbol{\alpha}-\boldsymbol{\beta},\boldsymbol{x}-t\boldsymbol{\beta}\rangle^2=0\\
\\
\mathbf{Hess}_{\boldsymbol{x},s}(\Phi)
\end{align*}
Is there any book that describes this method? I feel like this is very common, but I couldn't find a better reference.
